# Conda unable to find module that is already installed

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm new to anaconda and I am trying to figure out how its virtual environments work. I made a venv from the anaconda prompt and I installed 'pyautogui'. From there I went on VScode and continued my work and everything worked properly but when I tried to run the same script from the anaconda prompt it gave me this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'`.

The proper venv was activated. I was in the proper directory. When I run `conda list`, pyautogui shows up as one of the packages installed in the venv. I only get this error when I try to run it from the anaconda prompt or cmd. On every other ide/code editor it works properly.
What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing something? I'd really appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: how did u installed the module? (conda install... , pip install..., brew install...)

Comment: most likely you are running the python code from the wrong environment. When running `conda list` - if you see `pyautogui`  installed - go into the Python repl (by typping python) , and then write ` import pytautogui` . If it is imported then you know that previously you were running from a different environment.

Comment: @Giuppox initially i installed it using pip but then i uninstalled it and reinstalled it using conda-forge as suggested by Sachin but it still gives the same error. The only difference that i see is when i run ```conda list``` pyautogui used to have 'pypi' as its channel but now it shows 'conda-forge'

Comment: @skibee the import works. how do i go to the correct environment? from what i understand, ```(base)``` is displayed when no venvs are activated and the ```(venv_name)``` is displayed in front of every line when that env is activated and that is the environment that i'm running the code from. am i doing something wrong or have i misunderstood something?

Comment: @user14563079 just activate the environment by writing `conda activate <venv_name>` and then you are in the environment. Then you can run your code. If you are using an IDE you should check that it is configured with the correct environment.

Comment: @skibee i did ```conda activate <venv_name>``` and the code runs properly in an ide. the error pops up only if i try to run it in the terminal

Comment: @user14563079 so the code is running not from within the virtual environment. double check that when you are running the code within the terminal the virtual environment is activated

Comment: that's exactly what i did. i'll prolly just go back to using  an ide. this is way too much effort. thanks @skibee